# IE ActiveX' FileSystemObject - how to read local file with JS - help

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, file-io, filesystemobject

I am studying the FileSystemObject... The thing is I couldn't find any code snippets which show some conceptions as

- A) JS local File reading as binary stream
- B) encode the stream to base64
- C) images reading examples

So if you know some useful web resources to share links or you can share some code snippets it will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the desire to do the same thing. :D Your welcome to do this, but unfortunately IE8/IE9 fails to provide realistic access to the file system through activeX.  Theoretically you can enable the option in the settings, but it constantly warns you of inadequate security settings.

> WARNING Your browser has ......etc.

As an alternative I would advise using Java.  http://www.tiddlywiki.com/  Has the basis Java -> javascript interaction to mess with the file system.  The code isn't great quality but definitely has the the potential for a good intro.  As an added bonus Java works across OSs.

Comment: Well, as for now, I have IE 7 so maybe it supports it?

Comment: IE6 definitely not to sure about IE7.  Try downloading tiddlywiki.com and see if it runs.  It doesn't do property feature detection, so the script fails in IE if activeX isn't supported.  If you want to do system scripting I would advise linux bash.  If you want to do system scripting in JavaScript you should either use node.js or Java.  There isn't any dependable way(and futurely supported).

Comment: Emm... I don't worry about all these warnings because I am going just to test IE reading script on my own computer :) But I couldn't find any code snippets so that why I asked the question.

Comment: Do you look at http://tiddlywiki.com source or [Google](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=activex+javascript+file+system&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)?

Comment: Just give me a point... what the tiddlywiki.com gives in my case?

Comment: Right click `view page source` it uses  `ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` in numerous places, not to mention there are plenty of examples [here](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ActiveXObject(%22Scripting.FileSystemObject%22)).

Comment: But is there some standard code snippets from Microsoft or something?

Comment: Do you even look at the google link?  [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z9ffy99(v=vs.85).aspx) one is and the [Second](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I watched the JScript example as 
"var fso, f1;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
f1 = fso.GetFile("c:\\test.txt");"
but is there a base64 convert supporting snippet?

Comment: Please provide more information, because google appears to be a fine  [source](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=15&gs_id=1b&xhr=t&q=javascript+base64&qe=amF2YXNjcmlwdCBiYXNl&qesig=8lz2mrdulPFIzDAC5XLntw&pkc=AFgZ2tllCeixVw_lDuFoTdMFDNmxCtblI0Flz-ksY1CsNqo-XJTt0i82RgPFnA5e4maD0i1o_GFKIaENPPr8Nkn_tOIlTXKOEA&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=javascript+base&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=6a466a86c28e7859&biw=1280&bih=682)